# How to capture DISM output and reflect the status with progress bar using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to capture an image with this method

```
DISM.exe /capture-ffu /imagefile=e:\WinOEM.ffu /capturedrive=\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /name:disk0 /description:"Windows 10 FFU"
```

Reference:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-windows-using-full-flash-update--ffu
```

in the powershell I used this way

```
& DISM.exe /capture-ffu /imagefile=e:\WinOEM.ffu /capturedrive=\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /name:disk0 /description:"Windows 10 FFU"
```

and It show the command window while capturing.
Is it possible for me to create a GUI like progress bar while it doing capture?

Thanks for any advice.

I have created this PowerShell script. But while executing this

```
$Result = & DISM.exe /capture-ffu /imagefile=E:\TEST\capture.ffu /capturedrive=\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /name:disk0
```

The progress bar is not start or show progressing, it just show empty (white bar).
Please any advice.

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

## -- Create The Progress-Bar
$ObjForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ObjForm.Text = "Image Capturing"
$ObjForm.WindowState = 'Maximized'
$ObjForm.BackColor = "White"

$ObjForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$ObjForm.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

## -- Create The Label
$ObjLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
$ObjLabel.Left = 5
$ObjLabel.Top = 10
$ObjLabel.Width = 500 - 20
$ObjLabel.Height = 15
$ObjLabel.Font = "Tahoma"
## -- Add the label to the Form
$ObjForm.Controls.Add($ObjLabel)

$PB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$PB.Name = "PowerShellProgressBar"
$PB.Value = 0
$PB.Style="Continuous"

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 700 - 40
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$PB.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$PB.Left = 5
$PB.Top = 40
$ObjForm.Controls.Add($PB)

## -- Show the Progress-Bar and Start The PowerShell Script
$ObjForm.Show() | Out-Null
$ObjForm.Focus() | Out-NUll
$ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
$ObjForm.Refresh()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

$Result = & DISM.exe /capture-ffu /imagefile=E:\TEST\capture.ffu /capturedrive=\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /name:disk0
$Counter = 0
ForEach ($Item In $Result) {
    ## -- Calculate The Percentage Completed
    $Counter++
    [Int]$Percentage = ($Counter/$Result.Count)*100
    $PB.Value = $Percentage
    $ObjLabel.Text = "Capturing The Image"
    $ObjForm.Refresh()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 150
    # -- $Item.Name
    "`t" + $Item.Path

}

$ObjForm.Close()
Write-Host "`n"
```

#### Updated

I think DISM.exe can not report if it complete.
I have to make the progress bar just keep scrolling until this process finished.

```
& DISM.exe /capture-ffu /imagefile=e:\WinOEM.ffu /capturedrive=\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /name:disk0 /description:"Windows 10 FFU"
```

Anyone can give me idea please.

Answer (score 1):

Would [Write-Progress](https://ss64.com/ps/write-progress.html) be enough for you?

```
.....
ForEach ($Item In $Result) {
    $Counter++
    [Int]$Percentage = ($Counter/$Result.Count)*100
    Write-Progress -activity "Completion" -status "Status" -PercentComplete $Percentage   
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tatu , I tried it, but it the same thing with my solution, the progress bar is not strating it just show white bar while capturing. I mean while execute this `$Result = & DISM.exe /capture-ffu /imagefile=E:\TEST\capture.ffu /capturedrive=\\.\PhysicalDrive0 /name:disk0`

Comment: So your probelm is more about capturing the output from DISM. You need to start it in the background and capture the output. See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/815c880b-0338-40df-abb0-021cfeda288d/generate-a-gui-progress-bar-for-dism-or-imagex for example.

Comment: That's not helpful. The whole point is to show the progress that DISM has made so far... but control doesn't return until DISM is all done.